# Logic analysis - does this make sense

Tags: python

I'm trying to check encode with a round-trip encode-decode cycle.  I have a string variable (such as "dog").  I run it through my encoding function and get "jhb" (assuming a translation dictionary that maps (d:j,h:o,g:b)). How do I check this now?  I run "jhb" through my decoding function (now with the opposite dictionary (j:d,o:h,b:g)). This returns "dog", which equals original text.

My implementation below doesn't find the equality.  Help?

```
a = myfunction(text,dictionary)
b = myfunction(a,oppisite_dictionary)
a == b
```

Comment: yes, that would work (like caesar encryption). But I fail to see your question.

Comment: question is would a= b or should b=text

Comment: `b==text` if your routine does the job properly.

Comment: Yes thanks - the example i was given had a=b which did not make sense to me. Much appreicated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good variable names will help make this more readable.  The idea of round-tripping is that you encode a text, decipher it with the opposite reference table, and then compare the deciphered version with the original.  Look at this Python code:

```
coded_text = encode(original_text, encode_dict)
check_text = decode(coded_text, decode_dict)
if check_text == original_text:
    print "We did it!"
```

Is that easier to read and understand?  Remember, you may have to use this again in a few weeks ... or a few years.  My personal record is coming back to an algorithm in matrix linear algebra 32 years after I'd written the original code ... and then translating from FORTRAN to C++.